# Translate Obj-C to C# (Monotouch)

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

Not knowing Obj-C I could use some help to traslate this one line of code:

```
[[TVOutManager sharedInstance] startTVOut];
```

into a C# version I can use in MonoTouch.

I've managed to get the XCode project compiled to a static library, now I'm trying to figure out how to turn it on... The orginal project is posted here: http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/

TIA,
Rick

Answer (score 3):

`[obj myMsg]` is Objective-C syntax for sending the `myMsg` message to the `obj` instance. It is, at first blush, a lot like obj.myMsg() in C#. Objective-C uses message passing rather than function calls, however, so the two are actually very different semantically. You can often gloss over the differences, but if you are going to do any significant work on OS X or iOS, it's worth reading the Objective-C language [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) carefully. I'm not a MonoTouch/MonoMac expert, but I believe that the answer to your specific question is:

```
TVOutManager.sharedInstance.startTVOut();
```

assuming `sharedInstance` is mapped as a static property of type `TVOutManager`, or

```
TVOutManager.sharedInstance().startTVOut();
```

if `sharedInstance` is mapped as a class method in Objective-C.

Comment: Here's the actual Obj-C code:
+ (TVOutManager *)sharedInstance
{
 static TVOutManager *sharedInstance;
 
 @synchronized(self)
 {
  if (!sharedInstance)
   sharedInstance = [[TVOutManager alloc] init];
  return sharedInstance;
 }
}

Comment: sharedInstance seems to be a type (Global Variable) of variable, no?

Comment: @Rick, no in the ObjC code you provide, `sharedInstance` is a selector (a message name) sent to the `TVOutManager` class. `TVOutManager` is free to decide how to implement this method (and classic ObjC code would use a static (module) global).